# Manual commit messages with consumer group using kafka-node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to manually commit messages when all tasks are finished(like pushing message into database ), in my consumer group. How can I disable auto commit and commit messages manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [node-rdkafka](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka) instead. It works very well . you can commit a message like

```
consumer.commit({ topic: data.topic, partition: data.partition, offset: data.offset + 1 }, function(err, data) {})
```

Answer (score 2):

Set autoCommit false

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');

const config = require('../config');

const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({
  kafkaHost: config.kafkaHost
});

const consumer = new kafka.Consumer(client, [
  {
    topic: config.kafkaTopic
  }
], {
  autoCommit: false
});
```

Then commit manually-

```
consumer.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log('message', message);
  // feed data into db 
  consumer.commit((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Commit success: ', data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have did the same thing, but still getting the already read message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564644/getting-already-message-from-confluent-kafka-using-kafka-node-nodejs-lib